# Zend Framework: View variable in layout script is always null

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, layout

I set a view variable in someAction function like this:

```
$this->view->type = "some type";
```

When I access this variable inside layout script like this:

```
<?php echo $this->type ?>
```

it prints nothing. What's wrong?

My application.ini settings related to layout

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = "layout" ; changed 'default' to 'layout'
```

**Edit**

This [thread](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/model-view-controller-mvc-21/how-do-i-access-view-variables-layout-script-3774.html) suggests the alternate solution, but looking for solution to above problem. And this was working in Zend 1.6.2. I just upgraded to 1.10 and it stopped working.

**Edit**

If I set this view var inside any _init Bootstrap function, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to assign something to your layout you have to go an other way:

```
// get the layout instance
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

// assign fooBar as Name to the layout
$layout->name = 'fooBar';
```

Comment: @ArneRie: This is the same solution as posted in alternate link I mentioned in edit.

Comment: Just tested it with ZF 1.10.1 it works, please remember. You have to use <?php echo $this->layout()->name; ?>

Comment: yes, your solution works but my question is why view vars couldn't be accessed directly? And it used to work earlier. Please also see my 2nd edit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the layout view object and the action view object are separate instances of the Zend_View class.

I think this is the correct way to pass variables from the controller to the layout:

```
/**
 * Controller action
 */    
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->assign('myName', 'John Doe');
}
```

and then in your layout script you can access the variables by referencing the layout object like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $this->layout()->myName; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following entry in your application.ini file?

```
resources.view[] =
```

So, you can initialize the view with no options and use it through:

```
<?php echo $this->type ?>
```

Comment: Have you done the bootstrap of view through: $this->bootstrap('view'); placed in a resource method of bootstrap.php file?